# Java Jackson: get number of all subelements

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following piece of `JSON` code:

```
{
    "films": [{
            "id": "12345",
            "title": "The Fellowship Of The Ring",
            "year": 2001,
            "cast": [{
                    "actor": "Billy Boyd",
                    "id": "770911234",
                    "character": "Peregrin Took"
                },
                {
                    "actor": "Ian McKellen",
                    "id": "162659743",
                    "character": "Gandalf"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "67890",
            "title": "Spiderman",
            "year": 2021,
            "cast": [{
                "actor": "Tom Holland",
                "id": "162660329",
                "character": "Spiderman"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm fairly new to using Jackson and now would like to know, what would be the best way to get the number of all actors of all film objects with Java? Would it be to parse it from the movies object or to make a separate parsing method?

I have created a `JsonFilm POJO` that contains the fields of a film object and a class `JsonFilms` with getter+setter:

```
public class JsonFilms {

    @JsonProperty("films")
    private List<JsonFilms > jsonFilmList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<JsonFilm> getFilmsList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(jsonFilmList );
    }

    public void setFilmsList(List<JsonFilm> jsonFilmList ) {
        this.jsonFilmList = jsonFilmList;
    }
}
```

With an `ObjectMapper`, I can retrieve all films:

```
File jsonFile = new File(filePath);
        JsonFilms jsonFilmList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, JsonFilms.class);
```

Comment: Are you stuck with only Jackson?

Comment: 1) create classes that contain the actual fields. i.e. `class Films { List<Film> films; }`, then `class Film` etc. 2) use `Films films = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Films.class)` 3) iterate over `films.films` to get a single film, then iterate over a the cast of a film, accumulate the actors into a list.

Comment: @stdunbar I should mainly use Jackson, though I'm free to add other libraries if it can't be avoided

Comment: @Lino okay that was the way I was going about, but I was wondering if there is maybe another way to do this while parsing

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the titles and actors' names, you can use `ObjectMapper.readTree()`. Since `JsonNode` implements `Iterable`, you can `stream` all value nodes using `StreamSupport.stream(node.spliterator(), false)`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);

Map<String, List<String>> filmActors = StreamSupport
        .stream(root.get("films").spliterator(), false)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                filmNode -> filmNode.get("title").asText(),
                filmNode -> StreamSupport
                        .stream(filmNode.get("cast").spliterator(), false)
                        .map(castNode -> castNode.get("actor").asText())
                        .toList()));

filmActors.forEach((title, actors) -> System.out.println(title + ": " 
        + actors.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));
```

Output:

```
The Fellowship Of The Ring: Billy Boyd, Ian McKellen
Spiderman: Tom Holland
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create appropriate classes such as `Film` and `Actor` and parse your Json into appropriate structure of your classes, or you can do it quick and dirty and parse it into a `Map<String, Object>`. Your map will contain just one key `"films"` which will contain a `List<Map<String, Object>>`. You should iterate through that list and from each `Map<String, Object>` in that list extract a key `"cast"` that will contain a `List<Map<String, Object>>`. You summarize the lengths of all of those lists and that's your answer. In order to convert your JSON string into your `Map<String, Object>` you can use Jackson library, and in particular [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class and its method [readValue()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) or you can use an Open-source library MgntUtils that provides class [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) which is a wrapper over Jackson library anyway. With that class parsing your Json String would look like this:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = null;
try {
      myMap = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonString, Map.class);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
}
```

The Maven artifacts for MgntUtils library could be found [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils), and library as a jar along with Javadoc and source code could be found on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to add new libraries then the [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library could help.  The simplest code would be:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;

...

JSONArray result = JsonPath.read(json, "$.films[*].cast[*].actor");

System.out.println("there are " + result.size() + " actors");
System.out.println("they are:");
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```